# Div which appears, dissapears after a while and apears when hovering...

Tags: css, html, sliding

i'm trying to code a div which appears, dissapears after a while and apears when hovering..
you can see the live example at www.aedas.com - the left pane slides in, then it dissapears, and when you hover that area it will reappear.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something simple as this :

I am using setInterval and clearInterval for setting an interval for hiding the bar.

**Important Note**

id returned by the setInterval should be used by the clearInterval or the loop won't break!!

Working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/QmLAv/

```
$(function() {

   var showTime = 5000;
   var transition = 'slow';
   var target = $('.headerbar');
   var flag = false;

    target.slideDown(transition);
    var id = setInterval(function(){hide(target);}, showTime);

    var hide = function(item) {
        debugger;
        if(flag){
            return;
        }
        clearInterval(id);
        item.slideUp(transition);
    };

    target.hover(function() {
        flag = true;
        clearInterval(id);
        $(this).show();
    }, function() {
        flag = false;
        id = setInterval(function(){hide(target);}, showTime);
    });

});​
```